# Unity3d don't see the XML files in project folder after build

Tags: c#, xml, windows, unity-game-engine

I'm using XML files to store some data so it will be more easy to localize to other language, since Unity have problems with resx i have to use XML.

In UnityEditor everything works great, but when was i build it, it stop working at the first usage of XML.

I guess Unity just can't reach XML files for some reason, because when i try to manually put XML files to My Documents folder, and use reference to them, it worked.

this is current path to xml file:

```
Assets/Scripts/Core/Localization/lang.eng.xml
```

Works great in UnityEditor, did not work when build.

this is another (But have to manually put them here):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) +
           "\\testFolder\\lang.eng.xml"
```

But i don't like that, maybe there is some sort of way to make it work?

I know i can automatize this but i'm still don't like this. I thought it will be binary like resx (.resources) in game folder by default.

What is the best solution in that situation? If I have no choice I have to use "my documents" folder?

Thanks in advance.

---------------------Here is some code if necessary.-----------------------

To open xml files i use this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml.Linq;

private static readonly XDocument Document = new XDocument;

private static void OpenDocument() {
    try {
        string filename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) +
           "\\testFolder\\lang.eng.xml";
        Document = XDocument.Load(filename);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(exception);
    }
}
```

To work with:

```
  public static string GetEnumStringQ(Enum e, KindOfItemData kindOf) {
     string key = @"name=""" + e + @"""";
     string enumType = e.GetType().ToString();
     string kindOfValue = kindOf.ToString();
     if (Document == null) {
        OpenDocument();
     }

     if (Document.Root == null) return e.ToString();
     foreach (XElement el in Document.Root.Elements().Where(el => el.Name == enumType)) {
        foreach (XAttribute attr in el.Attributes().Where(attr => attr.ToString() == key)) {
           foreach (XElement element in el.Elements().Where(element => element.Name == kindOfValue)) {
              return element.Value;
           }
        }
     }
     return e.ToString();
  }
```

And this is piece of XML file:

```
<PassiveArmorSpecial name="StaminaRegenerationLow">   <value>Stamina Regeneration (low)</value></PassiveArmorSpecial>
<PassiveArmorSpecial name="StaminaRegenerationMed">   <value>Stamina Regeneration (med)</value></PassiveArmorSpecial>
<PassiveArmorSpecial name="StaminaRegenerationHigh">  <value>Stamina Regeneration (high)</value></PassiveArmorSpecial>
<PassiveArmorSpecial name="VampirismLow">             <value>Vampirism (low)</value></PassiveArmorSpecial>
<PassiveArmorSpecial name="VampirismMed">             <value>Vampirism (med)</value></PassiveArmorSpecial>
<PassiveArmorSpecial name="VampirismHigh">            <value>Vampirism (high)</value></PassiveArmorSpecial>


<TypeOfDefence name="Flesh">              <value>Flesh</value></TypeOfDefence>
<TypeOfDefence name="Bone">               <value>Bone</value></TypeOfDefence>
<TypeOfDefence name="Metal">              <value>Metal</value></TypeOfDefence>
<TypeOfDefence name="Rock">               <value>Rock</value></TypeOfDefence>
```

Comment: Did you mark your files in visual studio to be deployed? Select the file and in the properties pane see what deployment action is associated to it.

Comment: Yes, it was marked, but nothing happens. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your files into Assets/Resources to make them available at runtime. You can get them via by [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) method

XML files are then loaded as TextAssets.